# in android version 7.0 listview java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array but 5.1 v ok

Tags: java, android

This is my activity class When I use android version 7.0 it causes `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

But when use android version 5.0 or 5.1 its run smothly

```
public class AdmitedPt extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    EditText inputSearch;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ProgressBar bar;
    AdmitedPatientAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<AdmitedPatient> myPatientList = new ArrayList<AdmitedPatient>();
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admitedpatientlist);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        myToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.icon1);//set logo beside the Title
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);//for stop automatic keybord opening
        bar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.admitedPatientView);
        // onl();
        new HttpRequest(this).execute();
        // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }

    public void scanCustomScanner(View view) {
        new IntentIntegrator(this).setOrientationLocked(false).setCaptureActivity(CustomScannerActivity.class).initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                inputSearch.setText(result.getContents());
            }
        } else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }


    private boolean haveInternet() {
        NetworkInfo info = ((ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (info.isRoaming()) {
            // here is the roaming option you can change it if you want to disable internet while roaming, just return false
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }


    public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object[]> {

        Object resultObject[];
        Context context;
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        public HttpRequest(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        public Object[] findBedDetails() {
            CasesData c = new CasesData(context);
            try {
                URL url = new URL(String.format(Const.URL_IPD_ADMITED));
                //  String testUrl = loginUrl.substring(loginUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, loginUrl.length());
                System.out.println("Test Url :" + url);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                System.out.println("Connection stutus :" + connection.getResponseCode());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response1 = new StringBuffer();
                System.out.println("Response :" + response1.toString());

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response1.append(inputLine);
                    inputLine = null;
                }
                in.close();
                String response = response1.toString();

                c.setIpdadmit(response);
                resultObject = gson.fromJson(response, AdmitedPatient[].class);
            } catch (ConnectException e) {
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
                resultObject = gson.fromJson(c.getIpdadmit(), AdmitedPatient[].class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return resultObject;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object[] objects) {
            AdmitedPatient[] pt = (AdmitedPatient[]) objects;

            for (AdmitedPatient a : pt) {
                myPatientList.add(new AdmitedPatient(a.getADMISSION_ID(), a.getFNAME(), a.getAGE()));

            }
            myPatientList.add(new AdmitedPatient("LS1611001297", "KAMAL", "50Y"));
            //Error show in this line java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
            adapter = new AdmitedPatientAdapter((Activity) context, myPatientList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Object[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return this.findBedDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public class AdmitedPatientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    public ArrayList<AdmitedPatient> mDisplayedValues;
    public ArrayList<AdmitedPatient> mOriginalValues;
    Activity activity;

    public AdmitedPatientAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<AdmitedPatient> list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mDisplayedValues = list;
        this.mOriginalValues=list;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDisplayedValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)  {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout llContainer;
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.admitpatient_listview, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.llContainer = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
            viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column1);
            viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.column2);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textView1.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).ADMISSION_ID);
        viewHolder.textView2.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position).FNAME);
        viewHolder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it=new Intent(activity,CollapseView.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("my object", mDisplayedValues.get(position));
                it.putExtras(bundle);
                activity.startActivity(it);

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                mDisplayedValues = (ArrayList<AdmitedPatient>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                ArrayList<AdmitedPatient> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<AdmitedPatient>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<AdmitedPatient>(mDisplayedValues); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).ADMISSION_ID;
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(new AdmitedPatient(mOriginalValues.get(i).ADMISSION_ID, mOriginalValues.get(i).FNAME,mOriginalValues.get(i).AGE));
                        }
                    }
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is exception stacktrace?

Comment: in the Activity Class  
protected void onPostExecute(Object[] objects) {                    
  adapter = new AdmitedPatientAdapter((Activity) context, myPatientList)
}

Comment: that's not a stacktrace. Show the stacktrace.